# Can not access custom function of repository in symfony2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, repository, entity, symfony

Let me describe my issue
I have created custom function in repository for entity `TblUserEdu` in my demo application. My Entity is as below

**TblUserEdu.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserBundle\Repository\TblUserEduRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="tbl_user_edu")
 */
class TblUserEdu
{

}
```

I have mapped repository in entity and created test function in repository saved to path `UserBundle\Repository`.

**TblUserEduRepository.php**

```
<?php
    namespace UserBundle\Repository;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
    use UserBundle\Entity\TblUserEdu;

    class TblUserEduRepository extends EntityRepository
    {
        public function findEducations()
        {
            return $this->getEntityManager()
                   ->createQuery('SELECT u FROM UserBundle:TblUserEdu u WHERE u.edu_status="r"')
                   ->getResult();
        }


    }
```

have call function `findEducations()` function from controller.
**DefaulrController.php**

```
$edus = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:TblUserEdu')->findEducations();
```

But it returns error that function is undefined

```
Undefined method 'findEducations'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

I have tried many solution but every time failed to solve.

Comment: try with some other function name, like getEducations. I think that find prefix is reserved for the magic repository finds.

Comment: @ejuhjav, I have tried different function names but returns same error.

Comment: ah, true. My previous comment wasn't correct (as you can use the find prefix). But basically the problem then is that the controller doesn't find the repository class. Have you defined the namespace for the repository class?

Comment: Check under UserBundle\Resources/config/doctrine and delete any mapping files you find there.  You probably generated them earlier when building your entities from the database.  The mappings are interfering with your annotations.  Hence the repository is not being found.

Comment: @Cerad, Thanks its solved after removing mapping files. many thanks